# How to display monthwise and week wise records in case of following scenario?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, unix-timestamp

I'm using PHP and MySQL in my website. There is one table in my database named `users`. It has two fields viz.`user_reg_date(bigint(12)) and user_last_login(bigint(12))`. These two fields store the date in **UNIX TIMESTAMP** format. The whole table structure is as follows:

```
user_id         varchar(32)
user_title      enum('Mr', 'Ms', 'Mrs')
user_first_name varchar(50)
user_last_name  varchar(50)
user_name   varchar(100)
user_password   varchar(50)
user_email  varchar(150)
user_dob    date    
user_hybridauth_p_name  varchar(100)
user_hybridauth_p_uid   varchar(100)
user_reg_date   bigint(12)
user_status     enum('enable', 'disable')
user_subscription   enum('lifetime', 'period')
user_update_date    bigint(12)
user_last_login     bigint(12)
user_last_activity  bigint(12)
user_created_staff_id   varchar(32)
user_updated_staff_id   varchar(32)
user_registered_type    enum('online', 'manual')
```

Now I want to display the record counts i.e. the count of users whose `user_reg_date` falls within the dates of current week as well the record count of users whose `user_last_login` falls within the dates of current week. The other queries are also required to display such record counts of last week as well as last two weeks from the current date.
I also want to display the same record counts monthwise. Can anyone help me in achieving this? Thanks in advance. I ried to fetch such counts between two dates it worked perfectly to some extent. It is giving me the date wise count of user_reg_date but not the count of users last logged in. I'm just not able to write perfect queries. The query I written for this is as follows :

```
    SELECT date( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_reg_date ) ) 'Current Date', COUNT( user_reg_date ) 'registered_user_count', COUNT( user_last_login ) 'logged_in_count'
FROM users
WHERE user_reg_date >=1341100800
AND user_reg_date <=1374451200
AND user_last_login >=1341100800
AND user_last_login <=1374451200
GROUP BY date( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_reg_date ) ) , date( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_last_login ) )
```

Comment: do you have some error?

Comment: @vladkras: If you are talking about the query i wrote, then there is no error in the query but I'm geting only the count of user_reg_date. The same count is  getting repeated under the column user_last_login. This is my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```sql
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM users
    WHERE user_last_login BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY))
                              AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY))
  ) logged_in_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM users
    WHERE user_reg_date   BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY))
                              AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY))
  ) registered_user_count
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77c7d/1)** demo

Comment: `WHERE user_last_login > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)` works too [sqlfidddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77c7d/5/0)

Comment: @vladkras Can you please explain how does your proposal helps to get first and last days of the current week???

Comment: @phpLover Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columnName
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=1 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) Jan,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=2 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) Feb,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=3 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) Mar,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=4 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) Apr,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=5 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) May,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=6 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) Jun,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=7 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) July,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=8 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) Aug,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=9 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) Sep,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=10 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) 'Oct',
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=11 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) Nov,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REQUESTMONTH=12 THEN (REQUESTTOTAL) END) 'Dec'
FROM tableName
```